# Openlayers map undefined in a class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm kinda new in an angular (and javascript generally). I have this code

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


import OlMap from 'ol/map';
import OSM from 'ol/source/osm'
import OlXYZ from 'ol/source/xyz';
import OlTileLayer from 'ol/layer/tile';
import OlView from 'ol/view';
import OlProj from 'ol/proj';

@Injectable()
export class MapService {
    public  map: OlMap;
    private _source: OlXYZ;
    private _layer: OlTileLayer;
    private _view: OlView;


    constructor() { }

    /**
     * Function initializes the map
     * @returns {} Object of map
     */
    initMap() {
        this._source = new OSM({
        });

        this._layer = new OlTileLayer({
            source: this._source
        });

        this._view = new OlView({
            center: OlProj.fromLonLat([6.661594, 50.433237]),
            zoom: 10,
        });

        this.map = new OlMap({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [this._layer],
            view: this._view
        });

        this.map.on("moveend", function () {
            console.log(this.map);
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is on the last line. I'm trying to console log the object of map on moveend (so when user drag the map and release button- I want to load some data depends on the center of a map). **But the console says the object this.map is undefined** (even I'm calling a method on that object and It's working fine- It's called on mouse button release.

I guess It's gonna be something javascript special, some local or global object references, etc.

Can anyone help me, please?

NOTE: the initMap() method is called in the map component like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.map = this.mapService.initMap();

    console.log(this.mapService.map);
}
```

(In this console.log case its working fine, there is object of type _ol_map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the diff between `function () {}` and `() => {}`.

- In `function () {}`, the context of "this" is the caller of the function so here is "OlMap".
- In `() => {}`, the context of "this" is where you create it so here is "MapService".

this.map doesn't exist in OlMap.

To fix your issue, simply replace `function ()` by `() =>` into this.map.on().